# How to map example.com to www.example.com in webconfig or websitepanel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I Use ASP.net MVC and I use websitepanel and my  hosting in arvixe now i need my site just open with `www.example.com`

Now my site opens with 2 URLs:

- `www.example.com`
- and `example.com`

I need to open it with just one URL: `www.example.com` so that 
when user enters `example.com` as URL it would go to `www.example.com`

How can I do that in `web.config` or websitepanel config?

I do not have access to IIS.

Comment: Change the DNS record for site.com to redirect to www.site.com.

Comment: This is *so* not [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: @jaykob As I dont use websitepanel, I dont have any idea how to setup it. But, the point is you need to use URL redirect on your code. Please find the tutorial how to setup redirect on your code. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the same will still apply to your setup but I add the following to the **live** `web.config`. It will ensure a 301 redirect from non-www to www prefixed domain:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <clear />
         <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
           <match url="(.*)" />
           <conditions>
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
         </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
```